# Access variables defined in other controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
'use strict';

angular.module('sampleApplicationApp').config(function($stateProvider)
{
    $stateProvider.state('abcmanagement', {
        parent : 'parentmanagement',
        url : '/em',
        views : {
            'content@' : {
                templateUrl : 'scripts/app/abc.html',
                controller : 'abcController'
            }
        }
    }).state('newmodel', {
        parent : 'abcmanagement',
        url : '/new',
        views : {
            'content@' : {
                templateUrl : 'scripts/app/xyz.html',
                controller : 'xyzController'
            }
        }
    })
});

angular.module('sampleApplicationApp')
.controller('abcController', function ($scope, $state, $modal) {

       $scope.models = {};
       // logic to load models

});

angular.module('sampleApplicationApp')
.controller('xyzController', function ($scope, $state, $modal) {

       // I want to access models from above controller

});
```

Is there a possibility i can have access to models defined in abcController from xyzController ?

Comment: You can use services to access data in several controllers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two options:

1. if the controllers inherit from the same parent controller, you can store the data in the parent $scope (or $rootScope, but that's bad practice);
2. if the controllers do not inherit from the same parent controller, use a factory to share data between controllers:

`

```
angular.module('sampleApplicationApp')
   .factory('abcModel', function () {
    var factory = {};
    var model = {};

    factory.setModel = function(key, value) {
       model[key] = value;
    }
    factory.getModel = function(key) {
       return model[key];
    };
    return factory;
});

angular.module('sampleApplicationApp')
.controller('abcController', function ($scope, $state, $modal, abcModel) {
    abcModel.setModel('abc', "hello world");

});

angular.module('sampleApplicationApp')
.controller('xyzController', function ($scope, $state, $modal, abcModel) {
   $scope.value = abcModel.getModel('abc');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have, potentially, as many as three options:

1) If `xyzController` resides within `abcController` within your HTML then you can reference `$parent.property` ('property' being the name of the `$scope` property in the parent controller you want access to).

2) You could use `$rootScope` by setting any properties you want to access in multiple controllers like so, `$rootScope.property`. I would recommend avoiding this as it could pollute the global scope.

3) You could use an Angular service with methods for getting and setting the variables in question. Then you could simply inject this service as a dependency in each controller where you need access to these variables. **Recommended approach**

Comment: @vp_arth, true. Option 2 should be avoided at all costs. The only time I really touch `$rootScope` is when broadcasting events that other controllers are listening for, but even this I don't like.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is that you should create an Angular service which holds the variable.

You can work around it by using the `$rootScope`. Don't forget to inject it in both controllers ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you are trying to do.You can create a factory or a service,you can use $rootScope(not recommended),you can use angular's broadcast, emit method to achieve this.Refer to this example `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers`